# Using XAML how do I bind to a property of MainWindow from a different View?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a few public property/objects in my MainWindow (this window is set as my start up object). I want to be able to bind to those properties from a view that show from inside that window.

I can use the following code in my codebehind, and it works.

```
this.DataContext = ((MainWindow)((App)Application.Current).MainWindow).TippingSourceCollection;
```

I want to do the same thing with XAML.

Can anyone show me how?

Thank you
John

Answer (score 2):

technically it can be achieved via binding with static Source

```
DataContext = "{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current},
                        Path=MainWindow.TippingSourceCollection}"
```

but I would suggest to create specialized ViewModel class/classes for your Views

Comment: Thank you ash. I gave it a try, but no luck. I am much the noob...but my goal was/is to have easily accessible global access to the TippingSourceCollection...of which I can explain why if that helps any, but I would say that is a discussion for another post....

Comment: @Obbles, `TippingSourceCollection` should be a property (should have getter `{get { return smth; } }`) and it should be `public`. check VS Output window for any binding exceptions. also try for example `<TextBlock Text = "{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=MainWindow.Title}"/>`

Comment: Thanks Ash. If it works ok using the code behind. Would that indicate that the property is set up correctly?

Comment: @Obbles, no, not really. bindings are much more limited than c# statements. can you show TippingSourceCollection/window code?

Comment: It's a bit complicated to show unfortunately. I am using Developer Express MVVM framework and their scaffolding wizard. At this stage I have found a different way around it, and I think perhaps the way I am going about architecturing my application is bad (which is a seperate issue I suppose). Thank you for your efforts, at this stage I think I will try going a different architectural route....

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the Window's `DataContext` to the `MainWindow` object, surely you can just bind to its properties as normal... therefore, try this in your Window's code behind:

```
DataContext = (MainWindow)((App)Application.Current).MainWindow;
```

Then in your window's XAML, just do something like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding TippingSourceCollection}" ... />
```

---

EDIT >>>

Ok, so you want to do it the 'MVVM' way. One solution would be to put your `MainWindow` properties into a base view model class that all view models have access to. For example:

```
public class BaseViewModel { // declare your MainWindow properties here }

public class OtherViewModels : BaseViewModel { // specific properties here }
```

In this way, all of your view models will have access to all of the properties declared in the base view model. But then... *all* of your view models will have access to these properties, and have their memory footprint enlarged by them accordingly.

Therefore, I'd like to point out that MVVM has no rule that says that you should not use the code behind files for such setup code. The main reason to use MVVM is to provide the Separation of Concerns between the UI and the business logic that enables us to test them separately. As such, it is recommended that you do not put any business logic into your code behind files, however setting UI properties like this is not a problem at all.

Comment: Hiya Sheridan, thank you for your answer. I currently have it working like that, but my goal is not to have anything  in the code behind. I am attempting to learn/implement MVVM pattern in this project....

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. But it your methodology and trying to implement/learn MVVM may be a bit flawed having this collection on the main window, rather than in a static class that the viewmodel of the control can access when it is created.

```
<UserControl DataContext="{Binding TippingSourceCollection, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```

Comment: Thank you Jonah. I gave it a try but no win :( I think you may be right that my methodology/implentation/architecture may be a bit dodgy. (Ash above suggests that too) :) Perhaps I should go back to the drawing board